# I overfilled my engine oil double its amount and ran it for 2 mins

Tags: engine, oil, transmission

I overfilled my engine oil double its amount and ran it for 2 mins. working on my vehicle with only a french manual I though I drained the oil when in reality I drained the transmission oil (super black so should be done anyways). when I filled the engine oil I ran it for 2 mins then realized my mistake after I looked at the dipstick. finding the right plug and draining it off I then had to remove a air intake hose to get to a fill cap upon removing the hose I found a small amount of engine oil in it. the question is how bad did I just mess up my vehicle and what can I do to remove the oil?

Comment: If you didn't actually drive it and it's not smoking or knocking, you may have skated by with no damage.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the oil from where?

If the dipstick tells you there's still too much oil in the engine:

a) drain all the oil now in the engine.

b) making sure the drain plug has been reinstalled, fill the engine with whatever amount of oil it's supposed to have. The owners manual or a shop manual (or probably even the internet) will know how much that is.

Comment: and don't forget to refill the transmission